# Single Sign On SSO - Logout Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, logout

We are using Single Sign On service provided by a trusted partner. Our application is developed using asp.net mvc 5 framework.

We are facing issue with logout operation.This is our scenario.

1. The user clicks on the Login link, the request is redirected to the trusted partner site and redirected back to our site with authentication ticket if the provided credential are valid.
2. User performs operations in our site
3. when user clicks on the Logout button we are clearing our application session and cookie values and we redirect them to the home page.
4. The home page shows Login link, the request is redirected to the trusted partner site and immediately returns to our site with a valid authentication ticket.

Is it possible without making any change in the partner site to force the user to re-enter the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Single-Sign on is that the user does not need to re-enter credentials for logging into your site. The authentication is handled by your trusted partner site.

As long as your user is signed into your trusted partner site, the site will always return an authenticated ticket. The only way to force the user to enter credentials is to log them off from the trusted partner site as well. Maybe your trusted partner site exposes the API to log users off as well or re-authenticate them?